# The POM for jar is missing no dependency information available

Tags: java, maven

I get the following error

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.westgroup.caesar.uuid:wguuidJava:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for charliedog:argv:jar:0.0.1 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.oracle:classes12:jar:10.1.0.5.0 is missing, no dependency information available
```

But these jars and pom files are downloaded into my local repository from central repository Nexus. When I run the command `mvn clean install`, I get the above error.

Maven settings.xml file:

```xml
<server>
    <id>releases</id>
    <username>abc</username>
    <password>abc</password>
</server>
<server>
    <id>snapshots</id>
    <username>abc</username>
    <password>abc</password>
</server>
<server>
    <id>thirdparty</id>
    <username>abc</username>
    <password>abc</password>
</server>
<mirror>
    <id>nexus-public-snapshots</id>
    <mirrorOf>public-snapshots</mirrorOf>
    <url>http://maven.int.westgroup.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public-snapshots</url>
</mirror>
<mirror>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    <name>Nexus Public Mirror</name>
    <url>http://maven.int.westgroup.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
</mirror>
<mirror>
    <id>nexus-third-party</id>
    <mirrorOf>third-party</mirrorOf>
    <url>http://maven.int.westgroup.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/</url>
</mirror>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>development</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
    <profile>
            <!--this profile will allow snapshots to be searched when activated-->
        <id>public-snapshots</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>public-snapshots</id>
                <url>http://public-snapshots</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>public-snapshots</id>
                <url>http://public-snapshots</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
    <profile>
            <!--this profile will allow snapshots to be searched when activated-->
        <id>third-party</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>third-party</id>
                <url>http://thirdparty</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>third-party</id>
                <url>http://thirdparty</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>

    <!-- activeProfiles
   | List of profiles that are active for all builds.
   |-->
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>development</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>public-snapshots</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>third-party</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

I have uploaded these missing jars into Nexus repository into third-party repository.

[wguuidJava jar and pom file in my local repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfXO7.jpg)

Could you please let me know if I am missing any configuration in the `settings.xml` file?

Answer (score 2):

Everything is fine. You have a **WARNING**, not an **ERROR**.
This warning is related to how the jar was built and uploaded to the repository. It does not affect functionality.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I encountered the same problem and although it may register as a WARNING the maven build still failed.

Comment: Check the log. A WARNING should not fail a build. You might have a hidden error in there...

Comment: I think this warning can cause the build of a dependent project to fail if required (transitive) dependency information isn't made available.